# How force a python script every x seconds

Tags: python, multithreading

I have tried the `schedule` library however my code stalls sometimes which also means the schedule code stalls. Here's the code:

```
import schedule
import time
import app

schedule.every(3).seconds.do(app.run)
while 1:
    try:
        schedule.run_pending()
    except Exception as e:
        print e
        pass
```

`app.run` is the script, it using Queues and Threads to request exchange data. One of the exchanges randomly throws an error and because the of threading (I think) the code goes into a state of limbo. I can't seem to fix the bug, but a dirty fix to the problem would be force run the script every x time (in my case I want 10 seconds) Any ideas ?

Comment: You could use the [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) package to run the app in a separate process.

Comment: maybe look into setting up `cronjob` or handling it with `celery`

Answer (score 0):

the following code will work

```
import sched
import app
import time
seconds = int(input())
sc = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
sc.enter(seconds, 1, app.run, (sc,))
sc.run()
```

You can get more information [HERE](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sched.html)