# Running a simple period task with celery

Tags: python, asynchronous, celery

I can't seem to figure out how to get this working. I want to run a function every ten seconds

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals, print_function
from celery import Celery
import app as x # the library which hold the func i want to task

app = Celery(
    'myapp',
    broker='amqp://guest@localhost//',
)

app.conf.timezone = 'UTC'

@app.task
def shed_task():
    x.run()


@app.on_after_configure.connect
def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):
    # Calls say('hello') every 10 seconds.
    sender.add_periodic_task(10.0, shed_task.s(), name='add every 10')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.start()
```

Then when I run the script it just shows me a bunch of commands I can use with celery. How can I get this running ? Do I have to run it in command line or something ?

Additionally when I get it running will I be able to see a list of complete tasks along with any errors ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply with python threading module like below

```
import time, threading
def foo():
    print(time.ctime())
    threading.Timer(10, foo).start()

foo()
```

Comment: This is the reason I can't use your suggested method http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43038031/how-force-a-python-script-every-x-seconds?noredirect=1#comment73163074_43038031

Comment: The problem is that a bug in the code means that when an api request throws an error the code just freezes and doesn't progress. ie i need to forceably run the code every x period of time

Comment: Thats good to hear, but you can handle this situation using python exception handling, or try cronjob @DavidHancock